# Adding a variable to a ASP.NET CustomValidator

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation, customvalidator

I need to have a custom validator that can in some way incorporate a custom variable when calling the client-side javascript validation.  This validator is used in a repeater, and every item in the repeater needs to use the custom validator, but validating against its own variable.  Is this possible and how can I do it?

Example, I need its javascript validation function to be like

```
JavascriptValidation(sender, args, MYVARIABLE)
```

Or is there any way to incorporate my variable in the 'args'?  I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does the variable come from?

> i.e. is it available in the DOM?

If it is, could you get the value of the DOM node in your custom validator?

If not, it might be best to disable client-side validation and just validate on the server.

Comment: The variable is from the database.  Each record will have a different value for this variable.  I could make it a hidden field and get the value from that if that's what you're talking about, but I still need a way to get it in the custom validator's javascript method, and the hidden field would be in a Master Page, in a Repeater nexted in another repeater, so without being able to add its ID to the javascript call I don't see how I could incorporate that.

Comment: Looks like it might be easiest to just bite the bullet and set EnableClientScript="false" on your CustomValidator and validate solely on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted one article for [Client side custom validation in repeater](http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2010/09/customvalidator-registerexpandoattribut.html). It might be useful for others.

Comment: Please make this a comment, not an answer!

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for contributing an answer. In general, though, answers should be more self-contained. It's fine to reference more detailed information, as you have, but could you edit your answer to more directly answer the question and give an overview of the techniques to which you link?

Answer (score 0):

You might want an `expando` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you offer a few words of explanation for what `expando` does or post an example of its usage?